# Connecting two systems in python using sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Actually I am trying to implement bidirectional data transfer between client and server in two systems. I can send from client to server but the reverse is not possible. Is Bidirectional communication possible among different systems?

My client program:

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import time

SERVER_IP   = '172.16.142.29'
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port{1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.connect((SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
while True:
       mySocket.send('cool')
       time.sleep(.5)
       (msg, addr) =mySocket.recvfrom(1234)
       print(msg)
sys.exit()
```

My server program:

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )
print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    print data
    mySocket.send("hai")
sys.ext()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can send from client to server but the reverse is not possible."  - I see you have send and receive commands in both programs, so what does *not possible* mean? Do you get an error message, does nothing happen, do the programs stop responding, do you get a segmentation fault...?

Comment: You should use `(sock,addr) = mySocket.accept()` to accept connection from client and use the `sock` (not `mySocket`) for sending and receiving data.

Comment: @kazemakase **When running the above program I am getting the error(in server) as:**  `Test server listening on port 5000

cool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soc.py", line 12, in <module>
    mySocket.send("hai")
socket.error: [Errno 89] Destination address required`

Comment: @acw1668  **I tried that too but its saying** `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soc.py", line 12, in <module>
    (sock,addr)=mySocket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 95] Operation not supported`

Comment: Just notice that you are using UDP, so use your original code and try changing `mySocket.send("hai")` to `mySocket.sendto("hai", addr)`.

Comment: @acw1668 **Thanks it worked**

Comment: Since it worked, can either of you write an answer, in order to mark this as resolved? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Client Program:

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import time

SERVER_IP   = '172.16.142.29'
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port{1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.connect((SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
while True:
   mySocket.send('cool')
   time.sleep(.5)
   (msg, addr) =mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
   print(msg)
sys.exit()
```

Server Program:

```
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )
print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    print data
    mySocket.sendto("hai",addr)
sys.ext()
```

Comment: You should add some explainations. It could help to change this currently poor because code only answer into an acceptable one...